# Как понять в какой максимальной НФ находится таблица?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, нормализация-данных

Не могу разобраться в какой максимальной НФ находится данная таблица. Не вижу здесь транзитивных зависимостей, следовательно таблица находится в НФБК, но так ли это?

[image: Таблица "Бронирования"]

Comment: А что такое заселение и выселение

Comment: @Mike Это булевый столбец. В Java-коде гость сначала делает бронь, то есть столбцы Заселение и Выселение он пока не трогает, а когда "приехал" в отель и он заселяется то ставится true в Заселение. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

Comment: меня просто даты спутали. Очень странно выглядит что человек выехавший 10-07 при этом не выселялся. А тот что был с 25-07 до 28-07 все таки выселился. как то это соотношение столбцов нелогично смотрится

Comment: @Mike это планируемые даты заезда и отъезда при брони, а заселение и выселение происходит уже когда гость "приехал" в отель. Вроде в НФБК находится таблица

Comment: @Mike поможешь?

Comment: Зависимостей атрибутов друг от друга я то же не вижу. да НФБК